# how to use android studio 3.0.1 to merge more the one library module to one library moudle

Tags: android, merge

My android studio version is 3.0.1. My project has more than 5 library modules, one of them is a application module. The 5 library does not only use int in the application module but also publish as aars for another user to use. So each time I must publish 5 aars to others.
Are there any solutions to merge the 5 library modules into one library module?

Thank you!

Comment: there is no automated solution. Just copy the source in one library.

Comment: Also you may automate aars publishing =)